# parsing google maps direction XML request return 0 distance

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I'm using XML request for getting driving distance in google maps (C#, ASP.NET), my sample request:

```
string strURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" + Session["UserLat"].ToString() + "," + Session["UserLon"].ToString() + "&destination=" + tmpList[d].X + "," + tmpList[d].Y + "&mode=driving&sensor=false";
List<float> distances = new List<float>();
distances.Clear();
HttpWebRequest wRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
//Request.Headers.Add("Man", "GET " + strURL);
HttpWebResponse wResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wRequest.GetResponse();
if (wRequest.HaveResponse)
{
    if (wResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        StreamHandler = new System.IO.StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream());
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(StreamHandler.ReadToEnd());
        Response.Write(xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("distance").Count.ToString() + ",");
        for (int w = 0; w < xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("distance").Count; w++)
        {
                                                            distances.Add(float.Parse(xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("distance")[w].ChildNodes[0].InnerText));

        }
    }
}
```

It seems that some requests return 0 distance, of course each time I run my code I get different results, I've several points on map (about 19 points), almost half of them return 0 distance, I'm going to sort my items based on distance, but when I get 0 distance I cannot do anything! I'm getting my distances in a loop, what is going wrong here?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the directions api, but you may want to look at the status code in the returned data as you might be hitting a rate limit since you are not throttling your requests (at least from the example you've shown here). https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits#limitexceeded Also I would look into the distance matrix api since it seems you could get all your results in one request. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/